# Azure Cosmos DB change feed retry a specific document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using Cosmos DB change feed to solve some of our requirements. Wanted to understand if there is any retry mechanism available in change feed. For example, if I get a batch of 10 documents and 3rd one can't be processed for some reason, can I replay only the 3rd message again?

There are three ways of consuming change feed:

1. Azure Functions - Did not see ant retry mechanism for this.
2. Change feed processor library - If there is any exception in processing a batch of documents, all of them are replayed again.
3. Azure Cosmos DB SQL API SDK - Have not explored this in detail. But we have complete control on checkpointing, so we can probably replay starting from a failed message.

I am yet to find an option to retry only the failed messages from a batch of messages.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no such mechanism, would be good to have though. One way that *may* help is to use manual checkpointing (CheckpointFrequency in ChangeFeedProcessorSettings, ChangeFeedObserverContext.CheckpointAsync()). But note that even with manual checkpointing the atomic unit is still a batch.